# Pass java variables from Android activity to javascript in phonegap application

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am developing cross platform applications that target Android, iOS, Blackberry and Windows Phone Platforms. I am using Jquery Mobile 1.3.1, jquery 1.9.1 and Phonegap 2.8.0.

I want to be able to pass variables from an Android activity to javascript.

How can I call a javascript function from an activity and also call a method in java from javascript.

I browsed for a solution, but, could not understand the usage of `sendJavascript()` and `loadUrl()`.

Could someone please help me Understand this. I am new to Android and cannot understand how to get this done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using Cordova?

Comment: @AmitGupta He has Phonegap in the title and a tag for Cordova.  I think that's a yes ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution is**: Phonegap plugin.

> A Phonegap plugin bridges a bit of functionality between the WebView
>   powering a Cordova application and the native platform the Cordova
>   application is running on.

It is well explained with each platform in official phonegap doc.Here you can read more about [**Android plugin of phonegap**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins).
And here a very nice tutorial on [**how to Write a PhoneGap 3.0 Plugin for Android**](http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/) .

Comment: mvp,thank you for your answer. Is writing a plugin the only way to pass variables between the Android Activity and javascript ? My requirement is to be able to call a method in the activity from javascript and pass variables back from that method to the javascript.

Comment: it is exactly the need of phonegap plugin, it is simple- you can find many tuts online if the link i have given is hard to understand...